# Diagram for Default Task Process Workflow?

Tags: 2013, workflow, bundles

SDL Tridion 2013 has a default Task Process workflow definition (already in the CMS) that lets users assign and accept tasks not related to specific items.

I'd like to use this definition for basic scenarios and to maybe explain Bundle Workflows.

1. I think I can accurately create a diagram for this, but **is there a diagram or picture available describing the activities in Tasks**? It seems to have three manual steps, no automatic activities, and is as simple as it gets in terms of sending a task to another user or group and getting it back (or having it rejected).
2. **I'm able to to assign this Task definition to a Bundle schema and use with Bundle Workflow. Any reason not to do this?**

**Update:**

The workflow definition for `Tasks` is available to see from the Tridion Workflow Designer like any other definition. It's probably not a good idea to use it directly for Bundle Workflow, but we can use it as a reference.

Be sure a workflow isn't in progress when trying to save or open its definition. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 1, you can open it in Visio. It's just a regular process definition. By the way, there's an automated activity in there that you haven't worked out yet ;)

For 2, You can do it, but I'm not convinced that it makes sense for use with a bundle or single item workflow, as there's no real end result (i.e. no approval status change, no publishing etc.). Workflows associated with items usually do something with those items

Comment: Yeah it might confuse the point of the `Task` workflow definition (where Tasks aren't supposed to have items) to use it as an example for Bundle workflow. When attempting to open it, I'm getting `Open workflow diagram failed:
Invalid document identifier. 
WorkflowDiagram::Generate() 
OnClickOpen()`. I'll work on it a bit more to see if the error's related to my setup.

Comment: What version of Visio are you using? I was able to open the default task process without issue on the bootcamp AMI. 2013 supports 2010 SP1 or higher (32 bit). Check the other pre-reqs: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_719C8841C6ED4990B94377434832CD1B and maybe re-install the workflow designer if you still have problems?

Comment: Ok, duh. I had active tasks in progress. I finished them and  can open it now. Thanks!